# Pig Changing Schema to required type

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I'm a new Pig user.

I have an existing schema which I want to modify. My source data is as follows with 6 columns:

```
Name        Type    Date        Region    Op    Value
-----------------------------------------------------
john        ab      20130106    D         X     20
john        ab      20130106    D         C     19
jphn        ab      20130106    D         T     8
jphn        ab      20130106    E         C     854
jphn        ab      20130106    E         T     67
jphn        ab      20130106    E         X     98
```

and so on. Each `Op` value is always `C`, `T` or `X`.

I basically want to split my data in the following way into 7 columns:

```
Name        Type    Date        Region    OpX    OpC   OpT
----------------------------------------------------------
john        ab      20130106    D         20     19    8
john        ab      20130106    E         98     854   67
```

Basically split the `Op` column into 3 columns: each for one `Op` value. Each of these columns should contain appropriate value from column `Value`.

How can I do this in Pig?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve the desired result:

```
IN = load 'data.txt' using PigStorage(',') as (name:chararray, type:chararray, 
       date:int, region:chararray, op:chararray, value:int);
A = order IN by op asc;
B = group A by (name, type, date, region);
C = foreach B {
  bs = STRSPLIT(BagToString(A.value, ','),',',3);
  generate flatten(group) as (name, type, date, region), 
    bs.$2 as OpX:chararray, bs.$0 as OpC:chararray, bs.$1 as OpT:chararray;
}

describe C;
C: {name: chararray,type: chararray,date: int,region: chararray,OpX: 
    chararray,OpC: chararray,OpT: chararray}

dump C;
(john,ab,20130106,D,20,19,8)
(john,ab,20130106,E,98,854,67)
```

Update:

If you want to skip `order by` which adds an additional *reduce* phase to the computation, you can prefix each value with its corresponding op in *tuple v*. Then sort the tuple fields by using a [custom UDF](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.0/udf.html#udf-java) to have the desired OpX, OpC, OpT order:

```
register 'myjar.jar';
A = load 'data.txt' using PigStorage(',') as (name:chararray, type:chararray, 
      date:int, region:chararray, op:chararray, value:int);
B = group A by (name, type, date, region);
C = foreach B {
  v = foreach A generate CONCAT(op, (chararray)value);
  bs = STRSPLIT(BagToString(v, ','),',',3);
  generate flatten(group) as (name, type, date, region), 
    flatten(TupleArrange(bs)) as (OpX:chararray, OpC:chararray, OpT:chararray);
}
```

where `TupleArrange` in mjar.jar is something like this:

```
..
import org.apache.pig.EvalFunc;
import org.apache.pig.data.Tuple;
import org.apache.pig.data.TupleFactory;
import org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.schema.Schema;

public class TupleArrange extends EvalFunc<Tuple> {

    private static final TupleFactory tupleFactory = TupleFactory.getInstance();

    @Override
    public Tuple exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {
        try {
            Tuple result = tupleFactory.newTuple(3);
            Tuple inputTuple = (Tuple) input.get(0);
            String[] tupleArr = new String[] { 
                    (String) inputTuple.get(0),
                    (String) inputTuple.get(1), 
                    (String) inputTuple.get(2) 
            };  
            Arrays.sort(tupleArr); //ascending
            result.set(0, tupleArr[2].substring(1));
            result.set(1, tupleArr[0].substring(1));
            result.set(2, tupleArr[1].substring(1));
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("TupleArrange error", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Schema outputSchema(Schema input) {
        return input;
    }
}
```